# iOS/Swift: Keep "global" view pan from resetting other objects' positions, w/ AutoLayout ON?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, autolayout

Just started learning Swift, following the excellent [UIGestureRecognizer tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutoria).  It's got two images which you can move around (pan) and zoom (pinch) and rotate.  Works fine.

But then I tried extending it by adding a Pan Gesture Recognizer to the main view, so that I could pan the "scene" all at once.  Hooked it up to the ViewController in the same way as the two images.   Which works, but every time you pan in the main view, it *resets* the positions of the other objects, i.e. they move back to where they were at the beginning of the run, forgetting wherever you might have moved them to.

This is an AutoLayout issue (as described in thread [UILabel causing other objects to reset position on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103737/uilabel-causing-other-objects-to-reset-position-on-ios)). (Although I find this weird because there are no constraints at all.  Whatever.)

Turning off AutoLayout indeed keeps any resetting from happening, HOWEVER....
Ultimately I want to build an app using AutoLayout for other reasons, so I want to do it with AutoLayout on.

So, added some code to viewDidLoad() as per [UIView frames reset when using autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254479/uiview-frames-reset-when-using-autolayout),
namely in the Storyboard, I control-dragged from the "Main View" object into the Assistant Editor for ViewController.swift, a line that says

```
@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
```

and then in my viewDidLoad, I added

```
mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

But this has no effect, i.e. the reset behavior still occurs. :-(  No warnings about "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"  are generated.

Any help? Thanks.  Running XCode 7 beta 5.

Comment: Why even post the question if it's already solved? If you think it might help others, then post just the question (as a real question) and also post the answer and an actual answer.

Comment: Ok, will try to edit accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!  Ah.  So it's the OTHER objects, NOT the main view, that need this code!   i.e. code now reads...

```
@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var monkeyView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bananaView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //self.mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true // not needed
    self.monkeyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.bananaView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
}
```

With these changes, no unwanted resetting occurs, and yet AutoLayout is on! :-)